# Is there a name for this problem?

Tags: number-theory

I was just wondering if this is (or is related to) a well-known problem.

say we have some counting number N.  what is the smallest set S of counting numbers such that for each n=2,...N, there exists two elements of S, that sum to n?   $\forall n=2,...N, \exists s_i,s_j \in S$ s.t. $s_i+s_j=n$.

I was just thinking about this when thinking about the Goldbach conjecture.

Comment: Do $i$ and $j$ have to be distinct?

Comment: I was saying no, they don't (hence the 2...N; if they had to be distinct, you couldn't form 2), but I suppose i,j distinct is an interesting problem too.

Comment: I believe $\left \lceil \sqrt{N} \right \rceil$ is a lower bound on $|S|$, since for any fewer than that, you can't form N distinct sums.

Comment: This seems related to the $2$-stamp postage problem with $n$ denominations: http://oeis.org/A001212

Although you require exactly 2 stamps, rather than at most 2 stamps.

Comment: @Perry, thanks for the link.  Definitely a related problem.